# Group by ranges on 3 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to group by vehicle registration plate on different sites, how many times the vehicle has entered the sites, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

My data is like:

```
Streetname   vrm    0-9    10-19    19-20
Ebbw vale    xyz     1       15      30
Peel Center  M89GW   6       35      45
```

This is my query:

```
Select 
    t.t_street_name, COUNT(t_vrm) as MultipleEntries
from 
    (select 
         case 
            when count(t_vrm) between 0 and 9 then '0-9'
            when count(t_vrm) between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
            when count(t_vrm) between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
            when count(t_vrm) between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
            when count(t_vrm) between 40 and 49 then '40-49'
            when count(t_vrm) between 50 and 59 then '50-59'
         end as t_vrm 
     from
         [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]) t
where   
    convert (datetime, t.t_date_time_issued, 101) between convert(datetime, '2015/11/15', 101) and convert (datetime, '2015/12/17', 101)  
Group By 
    t_vrm, t.t_street_name
```

I get this error

> Invalid column name `t_street_name`.

Comment: Can you show the `[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]` structure?

Comment: Your query is messed up.  You have `count()` in a subquery with no `group by`.  Then you have `group by` in the outer query.  So, there are multiple problems.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, you created a subquery as a table and you are trying to fetch a column that was not selected on your subquery. you need to add that column `t_street_name` in order to the outer select sees it.

So try this way. Guessing here that that missing column is from the `[ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]` table. So

```
Select t.t_street_name,COUNT(t_vrm) as MultipleEntries
  from (select case 
               when count(t_vrm) between 0 and 9 then '0-9'
               when count(t_vrm) between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
               when count(t_vrm) between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
               when count(t_vrm) between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
               when count(t_vrm) between 40 and 49 then '40-49'
               when count(t_vrm) between 50 and 59 then '50-59'
               end as t_vrm,
               t_street_name -- HERE YOU FORGOT HERE 
          from
              [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]
          group by t_street_name
        )t                
        where   convert (datetime,t.t_date_time_issued,101) 
                  between convert(datetime,'2015/11/15',101) 
                      and convert (datetime,'2015/12/17',101)  
     Group By t_vrm, t.t_street_name
```

When you use a sub query it became you table therefore the columns for the outer query is only the ones you selected on the subquery, on your case just the `t_vrm`

As per the @GordonLinoff comment I've take a look at your query and see that what you really wants is called Pivoting Table which is to turn rows into columns, so to your problem the right query would be:

```
Select t.*,
  from (select t_street_name,
               case when count(t_vrm) between 0 and 9 then '0-9' end as "0-9",
               case when count(t_vrm) between 10 and 19 then '10-19' end as "10-19",
               case when count(t_vrm) between 20 and 29 then '20-29' end as "20-29",
               case when count(t_vrm) between 30 and 39 then '30-39' end as "30-39",
               case when count(t_vrm) between 40 and 49 then '40-49' end as "40-49",
               case when count(t_vrm) between 50 and 59 then '50-59' end as "50-59"
          from [ICPS].[dbo].[tickets]
         where convert (datetime,t.t_date_time_issued,101) 
                   between convert(datetime,'2015/11/15',101) 
                       and convert (datetime,'2015/12/17',101)  
         group by t_street_name
        )t
```